# Eclipse won't save its settings

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, save, settings

So I just downloaded the newest eclipse version and I noticed I don't have autocomplete. I went to the preferences and enabled them. I restarted eclipse and when I got back - still no autocomplete. I went to the preferences again and the checkboxes I checked were unchecked now. I tried doing it again without restarting - the moment I do something like

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.
```

and I press control + space I get No default proposals. When I go to check the settings again the checkboxes get unchecked again(by themselves). I added the source code from the jdk too. Still no success. I tried to download it again a few times. Each time to no success. I tried placing the eclipse folder in tons of different places - first it was in the program files folder (I run on windows 10 64), then I moved it to a non system drive it still didn't save. I tried creating a ton of new workspaces all at different places on my harddrive and still nothing worked. I tried looking for people with the same problem as mine but most say they fixed the problem by updating - I can't update because I just downloaded the newest Eclipse version. Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well sorry if you just found this on Google because my solution is just as dumb as most of the solutions out there. After the 2nd reinstall I decided to try again tomorrow as it was getting late. Next morning everything worked. I didn't even turn off my PC so not a restart fix.